# how to get the id of a link onclick using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi may i know how can i get my id of my links using javascript? the scenario was i have 3 links i want to get the element by tagname? is it possible?

```
<a href="docview.php?id=25" id="1">July 3, 2013</a>
<a href="docview.php?id=26" id="2">July 10, 2013</a>
<a href="docview.php?id=27" id="3">July 17, 2013</a>
```

I want to display the ID of my link the one i chose and then when i click n 2nd link the id of the second link will display. tahnks

Comment: show me your javascript function

Comment: Was anything helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:  the function is called when the link is clicked(you can also use other events such as onmouseover) it passes the id of the element to the function and prints it to the screen.  Hope this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="docview.php?id=25" id="1" onclick="myFunction('1')">July 3, 2013</a>
<a href="docview.php?id=26" id="2" onclick="myFunction('2')">July 10, 2013</a>
<a href="docview.php?id=27" id="3" onclick="myFunction('3')">July 17, 2013</a>

<script>

function myFunction(id) {
 var x=document.getElementById(id);
document.write(x.id);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, just want to know how can i change the value of may label? function myFunction(id) {
 var x=document.getElementById(id);   

document.getElementById('l_id').value = document.write(x.id);
} what should i put on the javacsript? thanks l_id was the id of my label

Comment: I just now noticed I could comment here lol.  Check below for the code you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery

```
 $("a").click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
    });
```

Comment: I think  jQuery is not mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Pure JS:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(this.id)
    }, true);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6NXC7/1/

As far as I know `querySelectorAll` is faster than `getElementsByTagName` or either JQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var anchor = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(var i=0;i<anchor.length;i++){
     anchor[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       alert(this.id);
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for changing the value of the label...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="docview.php?id=25" id="1" onmouseover="myFunction('1')">July 3, 2013</a>
<a href="docview.php?id=26" id="2" onmouseover="myFunction('2')">July 10, 2013</a>
<a href="docview.php?id=27" id="3" onmouseover="myFunction('3')">July 17, 2013</a>

<script>
var newString = "this is the new string";
function myFunction(id) {
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = newString;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the innerHTML property appends the current text to whatever you specify.  Also, you would change the event from onmouseover to whatever suits your needs.  Hope this helps.